# Do we need to use error handler middleware in ExpressJS for RestAPI?

Tags: express

I know that the error handler middleware is like the final person who gives a very generic message to the user when things get wrong. Like return 500 server error.
But I think it's not helpful for the user. Once we catch an error in routes or middleware, it's better to give the user a more specific error message for a certain error.
So I don't think we should use error handler middleware in this case then? Am I right?

Comment: If you _can_ give a more specific error, that's great. But if you _can't_, or it's a problem you simply hadn't thought of, do you think the client would rather: generic 500 "lol, whoops"; or request hangs indefinitely?

Comment: Oh. I see. You mean it's kind of insurance. Yeah, I think users prefer to see "whoops".

Comment: Providing a common error format is **ALWAYS** a good idea, specially for RESTful APIs! The client should be able to expect a consistent error format with minimal information. Such information can be a suitable HTTP status code or an internal error code. Based on the HTTP status code, an appropriate error message, "Whoops" for that matter, can still be displayed. But that decision should be up to the client.

Comment: Yep. I will research more for a proper and consistent response format. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the default error handler to give your users more specific error messages defined by you in your own custom error class

```js
const { CustomAPIError } = require('../errors/customErrors');

const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
    // for debugging purposes
    console.log('[ERROR]: ', error);

    if (error instanceof CustomAPIError)
        return res.status(error.statusCode).json({message: error.message});

    res.status(500).json({message: "Internal Server Error"});
}

module.exports = errorHandler;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I wasn't asking how. I was asking why. Is there another way to give you the reputation besides accepting the answer?

Comment: Well the answer to why is that it depends on your end user. If you are developing a RestAPI then most likely it will be used by other developers or your own team. In this case providing detailed (a bit more specific than "woops" or something) error message will be good because your end user is a developer who will surely understand it (technically).